# How to list all Computers Operating System while using different Credentials

Tags: powershell, error-handling, credentials, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

i try to retrieve a list of Computer Names and their Current Operating System.
Everything works fine up to the point, where I have no Access with my Credentials on this certain server.
For explanation: For log into the servers i have to use another Account. 
For every user ist CurrentUserName+"ad" (for ADministration)
The servers.txt is like

> Server1
>
> Server2
>
> Server3
>
> ...

Let me show you 2 tries.

1.

```
$Login = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name +"ad"
$cred = Get-Credential $Login
$servers = get-Content .\server.txt
$OS = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $servers -Credential $cred


$OS | Select-Object CSName, Caption, OSArchitecture | Export-CSV -path .\$(get-date -f yyyyMMd)_CurrentOS.csv
$OS | select CSName, Caption, OSArchitecture | Out-GridView -Title 'Current OS'
```

Everything is fine up to the point i add a Server where i have no logon rights.
After that i get the following error and NO server is succesfull.

> Get-WmiObject : Zugriff verweigert (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

2.

```
$Login = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name +"ad"
$cred = Get-Credential $Login
$servers = get-Content .\server.txt

foreach ($server in $servers)
{

    Try {
     $OS = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $server -Credential $cred -ea SilentlyContinue
    } Catch {
    Write-Host 'Logon Credentials not accepted. No access to'$Server'.' -fore white -back red
    } Finally {
     Write-Host 'Logon Credentials accepted. Grant access to'$Server'.'
    }
}
$OS | Select-Object CSName, Caption, OSArchitecture | Export-CSV -path .\$(get-date -f yyyyMMd)_CurrentOS.csv
$OS | select CSName, Caption, OSArchitecture | Out-GridView -Title 'Current OS'
```

The output on the Screen is fine, except the "Out-GridView" Here is only the last Server shown in GridView.

> Logon Credentials accepted. Grant access to DEBZIAPP104.

While adding this "bad server" i'll get

> Logon Credentials accepted. Grant access to DEBZIAPP104.
>
> Logon Credentials not accepted. No access to DEBZIAPP106.
>
> Logon Credentials accepted. Grant access to DEBZIAPP106.

I want to list all servers that are fine. If there occurs a server where i have no logon rights, there should be shown a message and the script need to continue.

Please ask if anything is not clear.
Hope someone can help. :)

Greets,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

`Try`/`Catch` will only catch Terminating Errors.

This should set you straight:

`$OS = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $server -Credential $cred -ea Stop`

Comment: That doesn't work. Test with the following servers.
DEBZIAPP104 - ok
DEBZIAPP105 - ok
DEBZIAPP106 - no access right
DEBZIAPP107 - ok

No server is shown in the output/ gridview